# Constructing a new axiom to force a desired conclusion

Tags: logic, soft-question

When a desired logical conclusion *doesn't* hold in a particular mathematical context, are there specific strategies for constructing an axiom that *forces* that conclusion to hold? (Other than making the conclusion itself a new axiom.)

For context, I'm formalizing a new type system for a programming language by first starting with an overly-permissive definition of a "type", and then adding (or updating) axioms as needed such that particular conclusions hold. (Both for computability and to match the user's intuitions.)

When adding new axioms, I want to avoid being overly restrictive or idiosyncratic, and I want to stay within a specific mathematical area, which is category theory in this case. In particular, I don't want to reduce the set of possible interpretations to $\emptyset$ by having contradictions.

So far my strategy has been to make the axioms somewhat irreducible and mutually independent, mostly so it's easy to show that they don't contradict each other. Although this usually results in axioms that are more restrictive than are strictly necessary, it has also led to some unexpectedly-useful side effects.